# Show records only belonging to that user ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

I have the following code

```rb
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h5>Name: <%= @user['name'] %> | Username: <%= @user['username'] %></h5>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">User details</h5>

      <ul class="card-text">
        <li>ID: <%= @user['id'] %></li>
        <li>Name: <%= @user['name'] %></li>
        <li>E-mail: <%= @user['email'] %></li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <h5>Address</h5>
        <li>Street: <%= @user['address']['street'] %></li>
        <li>Suite: <%= @user['address']['suite'] %></li>
        <li>City: <%= @user['address']['city'] %></li>
        <li>Zipcode: <%= @user['address']['zipcode'] %></li>
        <li>Geo Lat: <%= @user['address']['geo']['lat'] %></li>
        <li>Geo Lng: <%= @user['address']['geo']['lng'] %></li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li>Phone Number: <%= @user['phone'] %></li>
        <li>Website: <%= @user['website'] %></li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <h5>Company details</h5>
        <li>Company name: <%= @user['company']['name'] %></li>
        <li>Company catchphrase: <%= @user['company']['catchPhrase'] %></li>
        <li>Company bs: <%= @user['company']['bs'] %></li>
      </ul>

      <h5 class="card-title">User Albums</h5>

      <div class="row">
        <% @albums.each do |album| %>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
            <h5 class="card-title">
              <%= album['title'] %>
            </h5>

            <%= link_to "View Album", album_path(album['id']), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <%= will_paginate @albums, renderer: WillPaginate::ActionView::BootstrapLinkRenderer, class: 'margin-auto' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

users_controller.rb

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = HTTParty.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + params[:id], :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

    @albums = HTTParty
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
      .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
  end
end
```

All of my data is coming from an external API.

Where I'm running through `each` album I need to only show the albums belonging to that user because currently, I'm looping through all albums regardless of whether they belong to that user or not.

An album has a userId.

Comment: `@albums = Album.where(user: User.current)` ( `User.current` or whatever you do to find the user that's currently logged in) in your controller instead of `@albums = Album.all`

Comment: @Viktor - unfortunately, what the OP didn't state is that they are working with arrays received from external APIs, not ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: I missed out the controller code, added @Viktor

Comment: @jvillian ^^ please see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-select) to, um, well, *select* only those albums where the album's `'userId'` matches `@user['id']`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = HTTParty.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + params[:id], :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

    @albums = HTTParty
      .get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums', 
        :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
      )
      .select{|a| a['userId'] == @user['id']}
      .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh OK, that's pretty straight forward, massively overthinking it then. Pagination does seem to break, however, `undefined method `total_pages' for []:Array`

Comment: Try moving `.select` up a line.

Comment: what `. paginate` gem are you using — the typical ones are `kaminari` and `will_paginate`. Generally speaking what you are trying to do doesn't scale, because paginate is actually an Active Relation object, and so pagination is passed as a query restriction to the underlying active record SQL call

Answer (score 0):

On your controller's action responsible for showing that page you should do something like

```
@albums = Album.where(user_id: @user.id)
```

So that when you call @albums on your view, it will only contain documents pre-loaded in the controller.

Or, if you're using something like [CanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to manage permissions, you should be able to do something like that:

```
can :read, Album, user_id: user.id
```

So you would be giving **read** permissions to the user to see only albums that belongs to him.

Comment: I've added the controller code to the question, but I shall try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

the other person's API should be doing the pagination for you. It will almost certainly not scale the way you are attempting to do it.